# Anagram Algorithm Clarification

Tags: java, algorithm, anagram

I am new to this forum and wanted to ask a question. I have seen multiple people asking questions on anagrams but my question is related to this specific algorithm. I saw this algorithm which uses recursion technique for generating anagrams but a part of that algorithm is not very clear to me. I wanted to seek help in terms of why that specific step is taken. This algorithm outline is from Programming Interview Exposed. Here is the algorithm:

> If you are past the last position 
>        print string and return
>     Otherwise
>         For each letter in the input string
>               If it is marked used, skip to the next letter
>               Else place the letter in current position
>            - Mark the letter used
>            - Permute remaining letters staring at current position+1
>           - Mark the letter as unused

Here is the code for the same:

```
void permute(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    boolean[] used = new boolean[length];
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    char[] in = str.toCharArray();
    doPermute(in, out, used, length, 0);
}
void doPermute(char[] in, StringBuffer out, boolean[] used, int length,
    int level){
    if (level == length){
        System.out.println(out.toString());
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if (used[i]) continue;
        out.append(in[i]);
        used[i] = true;
        doPermute(in, out, used, length, level + 1);
        used[i] = false;
        out.setLength(out.length() - 1); // why are we reducing the size of out??
    }
}
```

It is mentioned in the code explanation that when the recursive call is returned, the last character is simply dropped by reducing the buffer size. I am not able to understand why are we dropping the last character? Can someone please guide. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Wow, that algorithm is a lot more complicated that what I'm used to seeing for anagram checking.  I'm used to seeing "split both words into letters and sort them, if the results match, the two are anagrams".

Comment: I think it is anagram generation algorithm rather then checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To revert the effect of `out.append(in[i]);` (which adds a character) and restore the buffer to the same state after every iteration of the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
    if (used[i]) continue;
    out.append(in[i]); // try adding the ith letter
    used[i] = true;    // and mark it as used
    doPermute(in, out, used, length, level + 1); // do all the permutations for the remaining letters
    used[i] = false;                 // undo what we did
    out.setLength(out.length() - 1); // at the start of the loop
}
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks biziclop!Lets say I have string abc and I need to get anagrams for it. So here is the recursive call-  For anagrams starting we a, we get 3 recursive calls : doPermute(in, out,3,1), dopermute(in, out,3,2), doPermute(in,out,3,3). when the length and level becomes it the recursive call returns and now each character is marked unused and the out buffer for that character is cleared till the first recursive call i.e. do permute(in, out,3,1). Then we will start anagram starting with b and will be using the same buffer out which is already cleared. Is that correct or still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is doing the following:

- From the set of all the letters, let's choose the starting letter.
- If we have got all of them set, then we print one of the possible anagrams.
- Else, then we are marking this as used, and we need to add the permutation of the remaining letters to the end.

So lets have the example here:

We have the following letter:

> e, x, a, m, p, l, e

Lets select the first letter:

its either:

- `e` and one of the possible permutation of `xample`,
- `x` and one of possible permutations of `eample`
- etc.

When we will select all of the leathers we will print the word created.

You can also think about it as a decision tree,
First you select one of the n letters, then you select one from remaining and once you have selected all of them (you got to the bottom of the tree and got yourself one of the unique anagrams) because in each step you have a for loop ( so for all of the possible decisions explore the lower levels of the tree) you will get to each combination and print it.

I really hope this helps.